# I want to make an if-condition: if input to questions1 equals 'value' -> print follow-up question 2

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm stuck, with does the input not trigger the if-conditional so that the follow-up question is posed? How to get it to work?

```
list = []

question = print(input('Do you have a job? Answer with yes or no.'))
if question == 'yes':
    salary = print(int(input('What is your salary?')))
    list.append(salary)
else:
    print('Go get one.')
```

Output:

```
yes
Go get one.
```

Comment: Don't wrap `input` in `print`.

Comment: @hmm you should submit that as the answer

Answer (score 1):

The `print` function returns `None`, so your `question` variable will always be `None`.

Remove the `print` function around `input`. `input` will print that prompt on its own. Same goes for `salary`.

With the changes, your code should look like this.

```
list = []

question = input('Do you have a job? Answer with yes or no.')
if question == 'yes':
    salary = int(input('What is your salary?'))
    list.append(salary)
else:
    print('Go get one.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Input prints the string by itself. You don't need to use print. What now happens is that the print function returns `None` and that is stored as the `question`.

This should work:

```
list = []

question = input('Do you have a job? Answer with yes or no.')
if question == 'yes':
    salary = int(input('What is your salary?'))
    list.append(salary)
else:
    print('Go get one.')
```

Also, try to avoid using list as a variable name, as it is used by the `list` class. Give your list a more descriptive name, for example `salary_list`.

Comment: Thanks adadadasdasdasdasdasd!

And also thanks for the tip with the variable name, didn't use it in my original code, but since they we are some hefty and long German words I changed it to list, didn't wanna scare you guys ;)